# Remain in interactive shell after newgrp?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For most of my projects my default primary group is correct. However, for one of them I need to set a new primary group before entering its environment in order to avoid permissions issues down the line. Currently this is a two step process:

1. `$ newgrp specialgroup`
2. `$ source specialenvironment`

I would like to reduce this to a single command. It seems to me that I should be able to do this:

```
$ sg specialgroup -c "bash --login -c 'source specialenvironment'"
```

I would think this would create a subshell in which the group is set to 'specialgroup', then create another subshell which immediately sources `specialenvironment`. However, it doesn't, so I am clearly mistaken.

Similar questions that have not resolved my issue:
1-[how-do-you-use-newgrp-in-a-script-then-stay-in-that-group-when-the-script-exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299728/how-do-you-use-newgrp-in-a-script-then-stay-in-that-group-when-the-script-exits)
2-[problem-while-running-newgrp-command-in-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18897/problem-while-running-newgrp-command-in-script)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
[ $(id -g) -eq 1234 ] && source specialenvironment
```

where `1234` is the GID of `specialgroup`; use the right number. This way when you run sole

```
newgrp specialgroup
```

`specialenvironment` will be sourced automatically.

Comment: Thanks, with some modifications I was able to get this working.